# Make sandbox around Function() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, sandbox

Can I limit the access of a string-generated function (using the Function constructor) to the parent/global scopes?

For example: the following code, as it is, prints *false*, because the function is storing/modifying the variable a in window.

```
window.a = 4;
Function("a=3;")()
console.log(a === 4);
```

Could I restrict the access to window/parent scope and make it print out *"true"*?

Answer (score 14):

Here is an additional idea which could be quite powerful together with Esailija's proposal (see the comments on his answer for the discussion).

You could create dummy iframe and use its `Function` function. The function created with that will only have access to the scope of the iframe by default, though it could still break out of it. Fortunately it is easy to prevent that, by the way Esailija suggested.

I could imagine the  function to be like this:

```
function sandboxed(code) {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(frame);

    var F = frame.contentWindow.Function,
        args = Object.keys(frame.contentWindow).join();

    document.body.removeChild(frame);

    return F(args, code)();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x62Zc/)

Optionally you might want to prepend `'use strict';` to the code.

---

This works at least in Chrome. Whether the function created this way has access to the iframe's global scope or the page's global scope can be easily tested with:

```
(function() {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    var same = window === frame.contentWindow.Function('return window;')();
    alert(same ? ':(' : ':)');
    document.body.removeChild(frame);
}());
```

Comment: Very creative :D +1 I get `:)` in all but IE8, where it throws a `doesnt support property or method Function`

Comment: @Esailija: Thanks for testing (I don't have IE). Maybe the iframe's source has to be set explicitly in IE (`frame.src = 'about:blank'` should do) or the property is just named differently (not `contentWindow`). If you have to set the source, maybe you have to wait for the `load` event before you can access the window but of course it's no problem to make `sandboxed` accept a callback for the result :)

Comment: Hi great answer, is there any ways to test all possible attacks sort of unit testing this? any explot list with this kind of scenario?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think so. You could name the globals you want to protect in the parameters so that they shadow them:

```
window.a = 4;
Function("a", "a=3;")()
console.log(a === 4);
```

But the function is going to have access to global no matter what you try... that's why it's called global.

Depending on what you are trying to do, there are other work-arounds such as web workers... and as always, [hidden iframe hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870104/995876).

Comment: Well, you could define `window` and `document` as parameters, to prevent direct access to them (as you already said) and then prepend `'use strict';` to the code to prevent implicit definition of globals. That might work. But of course it does not prevent access to existing globals as long as you don't "shadow" them via parameters. Maybe one could iterate over all `window` properties and create the parameter list automatically.

Comment: @FelixKling Sounds good at face value, I'm gonna try a few hacks to see if I can still get access to global

Comment: @FelixKling here's my current one, could work if you shadow `Function`  http://jsfiddle.net/dFmyd/

Comment: Creating the parameters from `window`'s properties seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Lz2BC/.

Comment: @FelixKling even if one shadowed `Function`, we still have `(function(){}).constructor`

Comment: True... well, it's not *perfect* of course, but it's something ;) Web workers are a good idea too actually!

Comment: Then there's all kinds of literals: `"".constructor.constructor === Function`... if one deletes all of those, in chrome at least, re-deleting brings them back :D

Comment: Have a look at my answer for a solution to this :) (I hope it works :-/)

Comment: You could actually shadow all globals by getting them with [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)(self) and calling Function.apply(...) ...but this would still leave the 'this' keyword, which will always be equal to the global scope. And it's illegal to have an argument named 'this'.
So this shadowing trick only can work with code passed to eval(), not Function(), which always runs code in the global scope instead of local.

Answer (score 2):

@Esailija's answer is right. Additionally, I would recommend limiting the number of global variables that you have to protect in the first place. Put anything that you would normally put in the global namespace in an `APP` scope that you control:

```
var APP = (function() {
    return {
        a: 4
    };
}());
```

There's no way to completely limit access to the global scope, but at least this way you only need to protect one object: `APP`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my adapted `sandboxed` function. It takes code and an optional dictionary with arguments to the function.

```js
function sandboxed(code, args = {}) {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    var F = frame.contentWindow.Function;
    document.body.removeChild(frame);
    return F(...Object.keys(args), "'use strict';" + code)(...Object.values(args));
}

console.log(sandboxed('return a - 10;', {'a': 34}));

// 24
```