# What is the best way to secure a javascript environment?

Tags: javascript, html, security, environment, emulation

I'm working on an HTML5 game, and as one of the features, I'd like the more advanced users to be able to write short scripts in javascript that can be run by objects in the game. The problem is that I'd like to restrict what the player scripts can do so they can't open new windows, cheat, modify the nature of the game, etc. I would, however, like to expose certain methods to the scripts so they can make useful things.

A few people have suggested that I could do this with Web Workers. Others have told me that I need to build an interpreter inside javascript to do this. Obviously, I can't just use eval, so how could I do this and what would be the best way, if there is a 'best' way?

Comment: Maybe you find this helpful: [Make sandbox around Function() in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11869582/218196).

Comment: who would run these scripts: just the one user or more than one?

Comment: dandavis, Certain groups of players could run certain scripts. I'd like it all to be interoperable.

Comment: Felix, perfect. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create a sandbox, Javascript has already done that for you.

If you create an iframe inside your page, that iframe will have it's own javascript environment that's separate from the original page.  Then you can use html5 inter-frame communication to send messages back and forth.  The iframe would run the user-defined program and send it's answers back to the host to be evaluated.  You shouldn't trust what comes back from the iframe and discard anything that is out of bounds.