# Is it possible to declare/call a function in such a way that outer scopes are not visible?

Tags: javascript, scope

Say you have the following code:

```
var something = "here";

function test(){
   console.log(something)
}
```

Obviously when you call `test()`, the console log will show `here` as it will go up through the scope chain till it finds `something` or reaches the end of the chain. But is there a way to clear out the scope chain so that it does not look for variables outside the local scope.

I know you can use `with`, when not using strict mode, to add to the scope chain, so is there a way to do the opposite, remove scopes from the chain or some other way to make outer scopes inaccessible.

The closest thing I could think of that would accomplish this would be to pass the function body to a web worker along with any arguments, and execute it in the worker and have the results messaged back. And of course that's extra overhead and a bit over complicated to achieve something like this.

Do not actually need this, or have a situation in mind of its use, but thought it would be interesting to see if it was possible or not.

Comment: Borrowing a context from an `iframe` may get you somewhere too.

Comment: of course you can declare local variable with the same name, but I have a feeling this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, Yea was meaning for something more than just declaring them locally :)

Comment: See [Make sandbox around Function() in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11869582/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling, Ah, didn't see that question, probably as i didn't think to search for `sandbox`. Should we mark this as a duplicate of that since they both are going for the same thing?

Comment: Your answer is more extensive, I'd say just leave it open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the question, the only way of I thought of doing this was with web workers. [Jeremy J Starcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094569/is-it-possible-to-declare-call-a-function-in-such-a-way-that-outer-scopes-are-no#comment35303027_23094569) mentioned in the comments about using an iframe, which I didn't even think of till the mention. So an example of that is provided as well.

### Web Worker Example

- All data needed would need to be passed as arguments.
- Browser would need support for

  - Web Workers (of course)
  - Structured cloning, used in this example

    - [Arguments must be clonable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm)
  - [Transferable objects](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#transferable-objects), not used in this example
  - If neither above are supported would require the (de)serialization of arguments to strings
- Requires use of a callback as worker is async (use promises instead?)
- Might be modifiable to allow binding the function to some context, but that would require the context to be able to be passed as an argument, have not tried this

Main javascript

```
(function(window){
    'use strict';
    function respond(oEvent){
        this.cb&&this.cb(oEvent.data);
        this.worker.terminate();
    }
    window.sandbox = function(fn){
        return function(){
            var worker = new Worker("sandboxWorker.js");
            worker.onmessage = respond.bind({
                worker:worker,
                cb:[].pop.call(arguments)
            });
            worker.postMessage({
                "fn":fn.toString(),
                "args":[].slice.call(arguments,0)
            });
        };
    };
})(window);
```

sandboxWorker.js

```
onmessage = function (oEvent) {
    var fn = eval("("+oEvent.data.fn+")");
    var res = fn.apply(null,oEvent.data.args);
    postMessage(res);
};
```

Test

```
//Assume jQuery has been included
function maliciousAdd(a,b){ 
    jQuery = function(){ alert("No it doesn't fix everything"); } 
    return a+b;
}
var sandBoxed = window.sandbox(maliciousAdd);
sandBoxed(1,2,function(result){
    jQuery(document.body).css("background","#3F3");
    console.log(result);
});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zm7rf/)

### IFrame Example

- If same-origin source, function could still access parent window etc.
- If using different origin, use of `postMessage` would have to be used
- Do not need to (de)serialize/clone arguments, in the case of same-origin iframe
- Synchronous, but could be made to be async as well.

Javascript: modified to use `Function` to generate inner sandbox function as suggested by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

```
window.onload = function(){
    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.src = "";
    frame.style.display = "none";
    window.document.body.appendChild(frame);
    var win = (frame.contentWindow) ? frame.contentWindow : (frame.contentDocument.document) ? frame.contentDocument.document : frame.contentDocument;
    window.sandbox = function(fn){
        return function(){
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
            win.location.reload();
            win.sandbox = win.Function(
               'fn','args',
               'fn = eval("("+fn+")"); return fn.apply(this,args);'
            );
            win.document.head.appendChild(script);
            return win.sandbox(fn.toString(),args);
        };
    };
};
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5UaAz/)

### Docs

- [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) ([Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage#Browser_compatibility))
- [Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) ([Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Browser_Compatibility))
- [Structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm)
- [Transferable objects](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#transferable-objects)

Comment: Regarding your iframe example, instead of creating a `script` element, you could also just use the `Function` constructor from the iframe window.

Comment: Good idea, implemented. Also would you think it necessary to block out the global keywords like you do in your answer to the question you mentioned?

Comment: Depends on the context. If you don't do that, then the inner code can at least access global variables in the parent window. But if there is nothing you want to prevent access to, then you are fine. But I'm sure there are still other ways to get a reference to the parent window (eg via `this`) so this approach isn't 100% secure either way.